# Python Match xx-xxxx Numbers - Inaccurate Results

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm quite weak in regex.

I'm trying to match a string which could be anthing like the following:

```
12-1234 *string*

12 1234 *string*
```

or

```
12 123 *string*

12-1234 *string*
```

As long as that pattern is found in a given string, then it should pass...

I figured this should be sufficient:

```
    a = re.compile("^\d{0,2}[\- ]\d{0,4}$")

    if a.match(dbfull_address):
        continue
```

Yet I'm still getting inaccurate results:

12 *string*

I guess I need help with my regex :D

Comment: What exactly is the desired pattern? At the start of the string, there can be 1-2 digits before and 1-4 digits after the separator (which may be a space or a dash), after that anything may follow?

Answer (score 2):

```
^\d{0,2}[\- ]\d{0,4}$
```

allows zero digits around the space/dash, so you probably want to use `\d{1,2}[- ]\d{1,4}`.

Also, you should remove the `$` anchor, unless you only want to match lines where nothing follows the second number.

The `^` anchor is unnecessary as well since Python's `.match()` method implicitly anchors the regex match to the start of the string.

Comment: So far this seems to be working great. Thank you for the help on that.

Answer (score 1):

```
reobj = re.compile(r"^[\d]{0,2}[\s\-]+[\d]{0,4}.*?$", re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)



Options: dot matches newline; case insensitive; ^ and $ match at line breaks

Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) «^»
Match a single digit 0..9 «[\d]{2}»
   Exactly 2 times «{2}»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\.|\*)?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
   Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «\.»
      Match the character “.” literally «\.»
   Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «\*»
      Match the character “*” literally «\*»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «([\d]{2})?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
   Match a single digit 0..9 «[\d]{2}»
      Exactly 2 times «{2}»
```

Comment: code without any sort of explanation doesn't make for a very good answer. Could you explain a little bit about why your solution works?

Comment: @BryanOakley explained.